# Is it okay to write code logic (if, for, while) inside your build method

Tags: flutter

I have some data that I need to show in the UI based on the date of the running time
so I'm doing something like this inside my build method after getting my data from the Consumer Widget

```
DateTime dateTomorrow =
                      DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1));
                  String tomorrowDay =
                      constants.dayFormat.format(dateTomorrow);
                  isWhileTrue = true;
                  while (isWhileTrue) {
                    if (myMainProgram.isDayShown(tomorrowDay)) { 
                      isWhileTrue = false;
                    } else {
                      dateTomorrow =
                          dateTomorrow.add(const Duration(days: 1));
                      tomorrowDay =
                          constants.dayFormat.format(dateTomorrow);
                    }
                  }
```

I felt that there is something wrong with my way of handling data and writing some code logic inside my build method but I couldn't think of any other way to do it.

So is it wrong to write things like this inside your main function? and if not what are my other options?

Answer (score -2):

No Its not okay to do like this because when ever the build function would rebuild by setState the data will revert.
The best way is to calculate in initState funtion.
InitState is the first function that is called when the widget is build and it runs once.

```
void initState(){
super.initState();
..your logic
}
```

Comment: Okay but there are two problems here, the first one is that I'm using a stateless widget and there is no need for setState, the other one, I don't have my data right away in my widget, and that's why I have a Consumer to get them